# atob() no reconstruye la imagen que previamente se decodificó a base64

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando parsear de nuevo una cadena de base64 a la imagen como archivo, sin embargo me está mandando el siguiente error

> Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window':
>   The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

Es bastante raro ya que la cadena de base64 en ningún momento fue modificada, necesito armar de nuevo el archivo para mandarlo como `FormData()` y que en PHP pueda ser procesado como `$_FILES`

```js
$(() => {
    let img;
    $(document).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }else{
            let imageType = /image.*/;
            if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }else {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    $('img').attr('src', reader.result);
                    img = reader.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
      let rebuild = new FormData('img', atob( img ));
      console.log( rebuild );
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<img src=""><hr>
<button>Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cuando obtienes una imagen como "data URL", se le adjunta el MIME Type delante, junto con la codificación, con lo que tu string es algo como

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNv....
```

Por tanto tienes que quitarle ese prefijo, puedes hacer algo como

```
img = img.replace(/data:.*;base64,/,'');
```

Para quitarlo y luego podrás decodificar el resto:

```js
$(() => {
    let img;
    $(document).on('change', 'input', function (e) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }else{
            let imageType = /image.*/;
            if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }else {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    $('img').attr('src', reader.result);
                    img = reader.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
      debugger;
      img = img.replace(/data:.*;base64,/,'');
      
      let rebuild = new FormData('img', atob(img));
      console.log( rebuild );
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<img src=""><hr>
<button>Enviar</button>
```